# Unable to cast Array<Codable> to Codable

Tags: arrays, swift, codable, swift4.2

Given that `Array` conforms to `Codable` I assume that an array of `Codable` i.e `[Codable]` should definately be castable to a `Codable`.

I've made a simple example with just the `Decodable` part. And just to verify:

```
// Attempt to conform Array to Decodable
extension Array : Decodable { }
```

This causes warning:

> Conformance of 'Array' to protocol 'Decodable' conflicts with that stated in the type's module 'Swift' and will be ignored; there cannot be more than one conformance, even with different conditional bounds

Which makes sense since `Array` conforms to `Decodable` already.

```
// Totally decodable array
var array: [Decodable] = ["Decodable", "strings"]

// Attempt to cast the decodable array
var decodable: Decodable = array
```

This causes compiler error:

> Value of type [Decodable] does not conform to specified type 'Decodable'

And a FixIt: `Insert 'as! Decodable'`

Applying FixIt causes runtime error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array<Swift.Decodable>' (0x11f84dd08) to 'Swift.Decodable' (0x11f84db18).

I'm using Xcode 10 on macOS 10.14.

So what am I doing wrong here?

I just tried with Xcode 9.2 and the same example works fine. So question becomes why does this no longer work on Xcode 10 and what am I expected to do instead? I can't find any reference to this change anywhere.

Comment: Please first tell what you want to do; what JSON do you want do decode?

Comment: @meaning-matters That would in this case be the strings "Decodable" and "strings". The point isn't that. I already know what the decoded data will be. You can replace every occurrence of `Decodable` in the example with `Encodable` and get the same errors. The point is the code won't compile.
@vadian `[Decodable]` means `Array<Decodable>` which means `Array` where `Element` is `Decodable`. The extension was just to demonstrate that Array indeed already conforms to `Decodable`, a requirement of which as you point out is that its `Element` generic conforms to `Decodable`.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In accordance with the laws of conditional conformance that went into effect in Swift 4.2:

- An array of some type (class, struct, or enum) that *conforms* to Decodable is decodable.
- An array of the *protocol* Decodable is not, because [a protocol does not conform to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

(What was happening before Swift 4.2 was that conditional conformance didn't exist and we were just getting a kind of universal pass; you could treat *any* array as decodable and you wouldn't hit a problem until runtime if you were wrong. Now, with conditional conformance, the compiler actually looks at the element type.)

Comment: Nice to have some clarity, I accepted your answer. Now since this worked fine in previous versions (and I mean the code didn't just compile, it worked in runtime), there should be some simple solution to get to the same behaviour?

Comment: I'll add a little explanation of that to my answer.